# find one sided limit to proof continuity

Tags: calculus, limits

there is equation:

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+} = \frac{ x\sqrt{x}}{x-x^2}$$

i want to calculate right and left side limit of x approach 1 in this equation, 
if we eliminate x, it supposed to be

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+} = \frac{ \sqrt{x}}{1-x}$$

then substitute 1

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+} = \frac{ \sqrt{1}}{1-1}$$

so the answer is infinity, is this true?

or -infinity? which one is true?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $x=1+y$ making $$\frac{ x\sqrt{x}}{x-x^2}=-\frac{\sqrt{y+1}}{y}$$ Now, $y\to 0^+$.

Your turn.

Comment: hello thanks i understand this better! i mean can you explain me the reason why you make x-1= y? is it to make the equation easier to solve?

Comment: @DevinaMuljono. In my opinion, it is always better to change variable in such a way that we look at the limit when the new variable tends to $0^\pm$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^+}\frac{x\sqrt{x}}{x-x^2}=-\infty$$

For $x\rightarrow1^+$  we have $x>1$.

Writing $\frac{\sqrt1}{1-1}$ is wrong!

Comment: Can you explain the reason? What makes the answer is -infinity? The root of 1+ / 1-(1+)= +/0 but - thats why - infinity?

Comment: @Devina Muljono For $x\rightarrow1^+$ we have $\frac{1}{1-x}<0$ and $|\frac{1}{1-x}|\rightarrow+\infty$, which says that $\frac{1}{1-x}\rightarrow-\infty$

Comment: i mean the reason why it is negative infinity is because the denominator? 1-x but x>1 so it is negative?

Comment: @Devina Muljono Yes, of course!

Comment: ah okay so first i just have to compute this equation by substituted x=1, so i got infinity as 1/0 then to decide whether it is infinity or -infinity, and after that i have to check the sign (+/-)  for both numerator and denominator?

Comment: No! We can not dived by $0$.  See please my previous reasoning. For $x>1$ we have $f(x)<0$ and $|f(x)|\rightarrow+\infty$ for $x\rightarrow1$. Thus, $f(x)\rightarrow-\infty$ for $x\rightarrow1^+$. By the way $\frac{1}{0}$ it's nothing! We can not write so.

Comment: i mean we cannot direct substitution? that the result is infinity?

Comment: @Devina Muljono The limit equal to $-\infty$, but we can not make this substitution because by the limit definition $x\rightarrow1$ and $x\neq1$. You can make this substitution for yourself if it's more comfortable for you, but you can not write it!